# app build submitted to app store connect with incorrrect version

Tags: ios, app-store

Not exactly a programming question so if anyone wants me to move this to another forum just say...

I've just added a new app build for release on Apple App Store Connect (1st time, taking over from someone on holiday), but instead of including the new version and subversion, I put the build number in by mistake.
It's currently waiting on review, but does anyone know if it's likely to be rejected because of this?

Comment: every build you submit to App Store must be increased by 1 may be major or minor version depends on you. Build submitted to same version as you submitted before has high chances of rejection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stop/remove the build at itunes.connect.

If it rejects, then archive the code with different build number no need to change version e.g 1.0 just simply change build: 2

If you want to change app version on app store then you can rename it. Follow below steps for it,
1. Goto https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/

2. Click on MyApps
3. Then select the app
4. Then select the row according to your project, see next image from my apple account

[image]

for you, it will show only one option, I have 2 apps so here it is showing 2 rows

i.e 1.8.8 Prepare for submission (which is not yet published)

and 1.8.7 (which is published already)

so in your account, it will show like this 1.0 or 1.1 Prepare for Submission, click on this

and come down to **General App Information** it will look like
[image]

Here you can change the app version number and save it.

That's it.